# how to fix connection refuse error using mail_sent function in Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

Hello I am new to Django, I am making a blog Project. I want to add sharing feature in my project via email. I am facing an Error Called Connection Refuse Error. Error Look Like that
ConnectionRefusedError at /URL/ [Win Error 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

**Setting.py**

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login('xxyz, 'xyz')
EMAIL_USE_TLS=True
```

where I defined my views function my views file look like that

**views.py**

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from Blog.forms import EmailsendForm
def email_send_view(request,id):
    post=get_object_or_404(Post,id=id,status='published') 
    sent=False
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=EmailsendForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd=form.cleaned_data
        send_mail('hello','how are you','xyz.d@gmail.com',[cd['to']])
        sent=True
    else:
        form=EmailsendForm()
    return render(request,'blog/emailshare.html',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Update below settings in your project settings.py file

```
ADMIN_EMAILS = ('yourmailid@gmail.com', )
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
if DEBUG:
    EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'testing@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587

EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<Your gmail account>'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
```

If you are testing it locally then you will see the mail content on your console and if debug is false then, it will send msg to recipient.